# isInViewport for Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I'd like to make something tell me once an element is been seen in the screen by the user, something close to WhatsApp blue arrows, or messenger read arrow.

I found [this](https://vanillajstoolkit.com/helpers/isinviewport/) javascript helper, is there something similar in Android (native, Kotlin or Java)?

```
var isInViewport = function (elem) {
    var distance = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
        distance.top >= 0 &&
        distance.left >= 0 &&
        distance.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
        distance.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
    );
};

var findMe = document.querySelector('#find-me');

window.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
    if (isInViewport(findMe)) {
        console.log('In viewport!');
    } else {
    console.log('Nope...');
  }
}, false);
```

Comment: Not sure if this answers your question but if you use a RecyclerView which contains the messages like WhatsApp, then you can attach an `addOnScrollListener` to your RecyclerView and see which view items are visible using `findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition` and `findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you to not implement this feature in a view specific environment.

If you want to implement something like `WhatsApp`'s seen notifier, you may simply override the `onResume` method of `Activity` or `Fragment` and then notify the `API` that the message has been seen.

Another method would be , if you want to be more specific, as you are using this feature in a chat screen, you may use `RecyclerView`'s `onBindViewHolder` method to notify the same.

From the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onbindviewholder)

> void onBindViewHolder (VH holder, 
>                   int position)
>
> Called by RecyclerView to display the data at the specified position.
>   This method should update the contents of the itemView to reflect the
>   item at the given position.